# Button in cell not responding on iPad

Tags: ipad, button, cell

I have a strange problem with buttons placed in table view cells on the iPad.

Here are two screenshots for better understanding (the button is on the right side and has a white background color):

[iPhone](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/822/bildschirmfoto20120724u.png)

[iPad](http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/856/bildschirmfoto20120724u.png)

No problem with the iPhone, but on the iPad this button is not responding. 
The positioning seems to be right, as it is drawn correctly.

This is the code from my custom UITableViewCell:

```
rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[rightButton setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
[rightButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
int xPos = buttonWidth-rightButton.frame.size.width;
[rightButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, buttonHeight, buttonHeight)];
[self.contentView addSubview:rightButton];

//buttonWidth = 310, buttonHeight = 60
```

The image and target is set by another class:

```
[cell.rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"options.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showOptions:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

I also tried this after placing all elements to the cell

```
 [self.contentView bringSubviewToFront: rightButton];
```

to ensure the button is topmost.

Didn't work.

Any ideas on this?

---

I still could't find a solution.

What I did in the meantime:

- visualized all objects placed in the cell (to display unwanted overlapping)
- disabled user interaction on all other cell objects

Any other ideas?

Comment: show us the code how you added the `UIButton` to the `UITableViewCell` and how you set the action for `UIButton`, please.

Comment: Can you give more detail, or write the code of button creation.

Comment: Updated my post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

First try this:

```
rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[rightButton setContentMode:UIViewContentModeCenter];
[rightButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
int xPos = buttonWidth-rightButton.frame.size.width;
[rightButton setFrame:CGRectMake(xPos, 0, buttonHeight, buttonHeight)];
[self.contentView addSubview:rightButton];
[self.contentView bringSubviewToFront: rightButton]
[self.contentView bringSubviewToFront: rightButton];
rightButton.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

[cell.rightButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"options.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[cell.rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showOptions:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[cell.rightButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Or you can also add a **tap gesture** to your button, it'll resolve the issue:
Instead of this line,

```
[cell.rightButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showOptions:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Write this,

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(showOptions:)];
cell.rightButton addGestureRecognizer:tap];
[cell.rightButton setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
```

Comment: I tried all your suggestions. But still no response on the iPad.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found something:

For the iPad the button only responds if it is placed in between the first 320 pixels horizontally.

Here is what the debugger says when touching the button (placed far on the right side):

```
(lldb) po touches
(NSSet *) $1 = 0x08249cd0 {(
<UITouch: 0x82c63d0> phase: Began tap count: 1 window: <UIWindow: 0x8266ca0;
frame = (0 0; 768 1024); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; 
layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x8266d60>> view: <SBMultiCell: 0x82cb8a0; baseClass = UITableViewCell; 
frame = (0 0; 744 93); autoresize = W; layer = <CALayer: 0x82cb830>> 
location in window: {713, 123} previous location in window: {713, 123} 
location in view: {701, 44} previous location in view: {701, 44}
)}

(lldb) po rightButton
(UIButton *) $2 = 0x082cd500 <UIButton: 0x82cd500; 
frame = (658 0; 86 86); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x82cd5e0>>
```

The touch location is exactly in between the button dimensions and also everything is drawn correctly. And as I wrote before, there are no overlapping elements or the like...